# Удаление секции конфигурационного файла с++

Tags: config, c++

Дано: конфигрурационный файл config.cfg

```
[section1]
key1=123;
key2=345;

[section2]
key1=asd;
```

Требуется: удалить секцию `[section1]` вместе со всеми ключами.

Для чтения и записи конфига использую функции

1. `GetPrivateProfileString`
2. `WritePrivateProfileString`

А для удаления секции или ключа не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть там для этого функция, просто у нее имя неприметное - [WritePrivateProfileStruct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725502(v=vs.85).aspx).

Пример использования:

```
WritePrivateProfileStruct(_T("Section 1"), NULL, NULL, 0, _T("C:\\test.ini"));
```

Comment: спасибо, все работает